# Why do you have to explicitly require some core modules in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

The documentation says there are some core modules that are shipped as part of the platform and are defined within the Node.js source. Looking after details, the nomenclature becomes a bit convoluted. "The term "global objects" (or standard built-in objects) here is not to be confused with the global object. Here, 'global objects' refer to objects in the global scope."

As I understand, there is a global object that is accessible by explicitly writing 'global', as in:

```
console.log(global)
```

It contains some things that you want to be accessed across all your files, like the console or the process object. There are other things that may appear global, but are not, they are there because all Node.js scripts are implicitly wrapped in the following:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
      // Userland code comes here
});
```

There are other objects that come as the 'implementation' of the Javascript language itself, like Object, Function, or Boolean.

What I don't understand, but still seems important though, is the following. Why is it then that there are some things shipped with Node.js that are available without any third-party libraries, but you still have to require them (like the 'events', or 'fs' module)? It seems to me that the whole reason of having a global object that is accessible to all files is that the core things that you might use can be exposed there.

I know that my question might be opinion-based, but is this just another implementation detail, or is there something that I do not get conceptually and should be considered in day-to-day development?

Comment: This is common to many programming languages. Python, for instance, has a `time` module, which you don't have to install, but have to import before use. I would imagine this is done so programs are lighter and faster if they than they would be if they didn't use some modules but included them anyways

Comment: Now I can formulate my issue more clearly. The Node envionment comes with multiple things that you can use. You have to explicitely require some of them (like file system operations module) and some of them are exposed as global objects, which makes them available without requiring anything (like the process object). Both of them come bundled with Node though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The documentation says there are some core modules that are shipped as part of the platform and are defined within the Node.js source.

**All** core modules are shipped with Node.js. That's the definition of "core."

The vast majority of them aren't loaded into memory by default, and aren't assigned a global identifier by default. To use them, you have to load them (via `require` or, in modern environments, `import`.) That's a good thing. There's no good reason to load the `fs` module if no code being run is going to need it, and there's **really** no good reason to create a global `fs` identifier — the global namespace is already overcrowded.